# Trying to copy all feature classes from one folder to another folder using python but it failed to run

Tags: arcpy

try:
    arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/WCGIS/Geog485/Lesson1"

```
fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

for featureClass in fcList:
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(featureClass, "C:/WCGIS/Geog485/Lesson2/PracticeData/" + featureClass)
```

Comment: an error was produced or nothing was written?

Comment: it just gave a syntax error but didn't specify where the error was

Comment: I'm guessing here but try a path join instead:  arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(featureClass, os.path.join("C:/WCGIS/Geog485/Lesson2/PracticeData/",featureClass)

Comment: Please always include full text of the error that you receive.

Answer (score 1):

Copy features is meant to copy a feature to a feature class in a geodatabase (http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/copy-features.htm). Since you're not copying your features into a geodatabase, try using `arcpy.Copy_management` instead (http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/copy.htm)

EDIT:
I was able to reproduce your syntax error with the following code:

```
import arcpy

try: arcpy.env.workspace = "file/path/1"

fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
print fcList

for featureClass in fcList:
    arcpy.Copy_management(featureClass, "file/path/2/" + featureClass)
```

The issue is the `try:` in front of the `arcpy.env.workspace`. Get rid of the try; if your code is written properly you don't need a try/except statement (which yours is written just fine, without the try). You should only use a try/except statement when you have debugged every other possible issue, or you expect a certain situation to throw an exception.

Comment: Just tried running the arcpy.Copy_management but it still gave a syntax error

Comment: what IDE are you using? IDLE?

Comment: Also, can you post an example of the code you tried with arcpy.Copy_management?

Comment: I'm using the Pythonwin

Comment: #Copies all feature class from one folder to another
import arcpy
try:
    arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/Users/Ellie/Documents/LESSONS/PYTHON LESSONS/Lesson1"
    #List Feature Class in Lesson1 folder
    fclist = arcpy.ListFeatureClass()
    #Loop through the list copy the feature class to the PracticeData folder
    for featureClass in fclist:
        arcpy.Copy_management(featureClass,"C:/Users/Ellie/Documents/LESSONS/PYTHON LESSONS/PracticeData" + featureClass)

Comment: get rid of the `try:` and add a `/` to the end of the output string for the Copy_management

Comment: I agree with crld. Though I do use try/except frequently in my code. Sometimes it saves you from crashing your system if a user provides your script with a variable you didn't plan on. But the catch is that if you're going to use "try:" you also have to include an "except" line downstream or your code will fail. You can read more about try/except here: http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/get-started/error-handling-with-python.htm#GUID-67136187-389D-4627-93CB-C47DFE1E46F2